# Populate huge data dynamically in SWT widget table

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to populate huge data in SWT Table. After searching the internet, I found the below code. But this code populates the hardcode data.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell( display );
    shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
    final Table table = new Table( shell, SWT.VIRTUAL );
    table.setItemCount( 10000 );
    table.addListener( SWT.SetData, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
        TableItem item = (TableItem)event.item;
        item.setText("Item" + table.indexOf( item ) ); // should be replaced 
        // by below for loop
     }
    } );
    shell.setSize( 300, 500 );
    shell.open();
    while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
       if( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
          display.sleep();
       }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

I want to populate something like below inside the table.addListener handle event. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < informationList.size(); i++) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(informationTable, SWT.CENTER);
        item.setText(1, informationList.get(i).getName());
        item.setText(2, "");
        item.setText(3, "");
        item.setText(4, ""+informationList.get(i).getId());

 }
```

Comment: Use a [Virtual Table](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-Virtual/Virtual-in-SWT.html)

Comment: Trying on a Virtual Table will be really useful.

Comment: I think he already tried virtual table, as you see he use SWT.VIRTUAL.

Comment: What is the question? You are not sure how to populate the data or the data populates too slow?

Comment: @MilenGrigorov Just specifying SWT.VIRTUAL is not enough to make it a proper virtual table, you have to listen for the SWT.SetData event as well as described in the link.

Comment: @greg-449 You are correct! I missed that.

Comment: @greg-449 - Thank you. I am able to populate the data

Answer (score 1):

A virtual table asks via the listener for the contents of the currently visible rows. That's what the virtual table is all about: *"Don't call us, we'll call you!"*

```
table.addListener(SWT.SetData, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
        TableItem item = (TableItem)event.item;
        int index = table.indexOf(item);
        item.setText(1, informationList.get(index).getName());
        item.setText(2, "");
        item.setText(3, "");
        item.setText(4, "" + informationList.get(index).getId());
    }
});
```

See also [Javadoc of the `Table` widget which also contains an example](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html) (highlighting by me):

> Style `VIRTUAL` is used to create a Table whose TableItems are to be
>   **populated** by the client on an **on-demand** basis instead of up-front.
>   This can provide significant performance improvements for tables that
>   are very large or for which TableItem population is expensive (for
>   example, retrieving values from an external source).
>
> Here is an example of using a Table with style `VIRTUAL`:
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by implementing it like

```
    final String [] names = new String [informationList.size()];
    final int [] ids = new int [informationList.size()];
    table.setItemCount(informationList);
    for (int i = 0; i < informationList.size(); i++) {
        names [i] = informationList.get(i).getName();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < informationList.size(); i++) {
        ids [i] = informationList.get(i).getId();
    }

    table.addListener(SWT.SetData, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            TableItem item = (TableItem)event.item;
            int index = event.index;
            item.setText(1, names [index]);
            item.setText(2, "");
            item.setText(3, "");
            item.setText(4, ""+ids [index]);
        }
    });
```